# UVM SV: Package includes file included in sub-packages as well

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

My SV-UVM environment is built like this:

```
Package pkgA;
   `include "file1.sv";
endpackage

Package pkgB;
  `include "file1.sv";
endpackage

Package pkgC;
   import pkgA::*;
   import pkgB::*;

   `include "file1.sv";
   `include "pkgA.sv";
   `include "pkgB.sv";
endpackage
```

I get the following error:

> file1 cannot be resolved, as it is defined in package pkgA and package pkgB which are both wild card imported

How do I solve this?

Comment: You need to show what is inside "file1.sv" and why it needs to be included in `pkgA` `pkgB`, and `pkgC`. Is it just text macros? And why are you importing and including `pkgA` and `pkgB` into `pkgC`? Please see http://go.mentor.com/package-import-versus-include if you are having trouble understanding the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try put all the files in the same directory as your run directory.  I think it is just relative path problem in your compile script.  You need to set up the include path in the when you call the verilog compiler.